# Is the resonance of a wine glass and resonance in an electrical circuit the same thing?

Tags: resonance

I am quite a noob at Physics, but I find it quite interesting, and resonance was especially intriguing when I first found out about it, but now that I have done a little bit of research, I either get results of a wine glass (or any object) breaking by the use of its natural frequency or I get a video/article that explains resonance in a circuit with an inductor and capacitor. Is the concept that allows both of these phenomena the same thing? Or are they completely different things that are just coincidentally called resonance?

Comment: [Examples of resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance#Examples)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, resonance in both these different phenomena is conceptually the same thing: it is when external driving force and velocity of the driven object (e.g. the electromotive force acting on current, and the current) oscillate not only with same frequency, but also in phase. This can happen only when frequency of the external oscillating force is equal to the so-called natural frequency (or resonant frequency) of the object, which is determined by object's properties such as mass, stiffness, or in case of a circuit, by inductances, capacitances and resistances of its components.

From mechanics of driven harmonic oscillator we know that in such phase agreement, transfer of work to the oscillating body is the most efficient one (think of a person pushing a child on a swing, it's easiest when phases match).

Comment: It's also "the same thing" in resonance production, e.g. $\pi + p \rightarrow \Delta \rightarrow \pi + p$. See: Breit Wigner distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It clarified things quite a bit.